# Omniauth facebook authentication failure Invalid application Id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I am using *omniauth-facebook* gem to authorize using facebook in my rails application.

I have followed [these](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview) instructions but the problem I am facing is error about invalid credentials:

```
(facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"error":{"message":"Error validating application. Invalid application ID.","type":"OAuthException","code":101}}
```

What is weird about this is that I am getting user info even though I get this error from facebook api.

the value of `request.env['omniauth.auth']`
is(server log).

```
#<OmniAuth::AuthHash credentials=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash expires=true 
expires_at=1421256863 token="some_long_value"> extra=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash 
raw_info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash education=[#<OmniAuth::AuthHash school=
#<OmniAuth::AuthHash id="174179219354091" name="Udacity"> type="College">]
email="ashish@gmail.com" favorite_athletes=[#<OmniAuth::AuthHash id="51926382304"  
name="Derrick Rose">, #<OmniAuth::AuthHash id="344128252278047" name="Sachin   
Tendulkar">,.... so on
```

**routes.rb**

`devise_for :users, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks"}`

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do 
  provider :facebook, 'key', 'secret', {:provider_ignores_state => true}
  # key and secret are correctly added in above line
end
```

**app/model/user.rb**

```
devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
```

**app/controller/omniauth_callback_controller.rb**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook
    omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    # Other code to create authentication and other logic
    puts "===>>> Omniauth is #{omniauth}"
  end

  def failure
    res = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    puts "======>>>>>> Authentication failed #{res}"
    redirect_to root_path
  end  
end
```

Every time response goes to `failure` method but not to facebook method.

What I don't understand is when I am getting invalid credentials error from api then how come I get all the data from facebook. I doubt I have something wrong on my end while handling the callback from facebook.
Can anyone point where the problem can be?

I am pretty sure I am using correct application id and key I am getting data from facebook in the response.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: did you get this figured out?